Show that for all $z \in H^1(0, 1)$ and for any $\alpha >1$, $\int_0^1t^{\alpha-2}\left(z(t) - z(1) \right)^2dt \leq C\int_0^1t^\alpha (z'(t))^2dt$
Using the fact that for $v \in H_0^1[0,\infty)$,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{v\left(x\right)^2}{x^2}dx \leq 4\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(v'\left(x\right)\right)^2dx,
\end{equation*}
show that, for any $\alpha >1$,
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1t^{\alpha-2}\left(z(t) - z(1) \right)^2dt \leq C\int_0^1t^\alpha (z'(t))^2dt,
\end{equation*}
for all $z \in H^1(0, 1)$.
I understand that the first inequality holds for more general functions if it is phrased in terms of an indefinite integral. I'm not sure exactly how to go from the first to the second inequality however. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Hi John, welcome to Mathematics SE!  Could you clarify what you mean by $z(0,1) \in H^1?$

@almosteverywhere I think he meant $z\in H^1(0,1)$.

Sorry yes you're right. I'll correct.

Are you sure about the restriction on $\alpha$?

Yeah pretty sure, how come?

It seems to be valid for $0 < \alpha < 1$.

What makes you say that? I think I've got a rough proof for $\alpha>1$ so I'll try and write it up for later today.

Just reupping this in case anyone can help. Any solutions, whether they use the given inequality or not, would be appreciated. It doesn't look too difficult to prove but I can't for some reason.
